# Why can’t the concatenated variable 'new_path' work but the whole string 'full_path' can

Tags: python, file, os.path

I tried to figure out whether **some images stored by the name** in a text file exists in a specific image folder.

The **text file** looks like this (including 1k lines) :

4916849840_43930a0979_o.png

331595384_492146dbf3_k.png

13517809023_f49228b3ec_o.png

So I wrote the code like:

```
import os

txt_path = '/Users/owner/Desktop/360_dataset_3k/train/train_3k_1.txt'
images_path = '/Users/owner/Desktop/360_dataset_3k/360_512_3k_1/'
full_path = '/Users/owner/Desktop/360_dataset_3k/360_512_3k_1/27107804622_984dbb2181_o.png'

f = open(txt_path,"r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    new_path = os.path.join(images_path, line)
    print(new_path)
    if os.path.exists(new_path):
        print("True.\n")
    else:
        print("False.\n")
```

However, the outputs are endless **False**.
BUT, when I replaced the **new_path** here

```
if os.path.exists(new_path):
        print("True.\n")
```

with the variable **full_path** which is a print of new_path created by a line in lines.

```
if os.path.exists(full_path):
        print("True.\n")
```

The outputs are **True**!!!

And after checking in a rather tedious way, it turns out they do exist in the image folder.
Can somebody tell me what is going on please? THANKS SO MUCH.

Comment: Sample of input text file missing. Upload it

Comment: Already uploaded in the very beginning of the question~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the readlines() method for file object, each line has a newline character `('\n')` at the end. You need to strip line before joining the path.

Code:

```
f = open(txt_path,"r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()  #Remove whitespace
    new_path = os.path.join(images_path, line)
    print(new_path)
    if os.path.exists(new_path):
        print("True.\n")
    else:
        print("False.\n")
```

Also close file object `f.close()` when task is done.

Comment: OMG, it works! THANK U SO MUCH! And I will remember to close the file object next time~